# CheckBoxTreeSelectionModel setSelectionPaths take long time

Tags: java, jide

I have a panel that contains a checkboxTree , I populate the tree when open the panel , the problem is when i have to much items to be selected in the checkboxtree (about 4000) the panel take a long time to open .
this is my code:

checkBoxTree.getCheckBoxTreeSelectionModel().setDigIn(true);

```
    List<TreePath> paths = new ArrayList<TreePath>();
    Enumeration<?> e = projectNode.breadthFirstEnumeration();

    while (e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        IconNode node = (IconNode) e.nextElement();
        if(node.isLeaf() && node.isSelected())
            paths.add(new TreePath(node.getPath()));
    }

    TreePath[] array = new TreePath[paths.size()];
    array =  paths.toArray(new TreePath[0]);        
    checkBoxTree.getCheckBoxTreeSelectionModel().setSelectionPaths(array);
```

any suggestions will be welcomed :) ,

Comment: having 4000 checkbox is a bad idea in terms of usability too.. can't you use something else.. like select dropdown .. or first reduce the number of usecases for which you require 4000 checkboxes

Comment: this is the requirement :( I need to show all elements in the tree and check the already selected elements